# Migrate non function script from HTML to JS file

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

As a begineer i am facing a problem, i followed an advise from several opinions to keep my HTML file clean, so i created a JS file and started migrating all scripts to a it, everything is Ok until i had to make this in it :

```
<script>
document.getElementById("mobile-toggle").addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById("mobile-date").innerHTML = "Today is ...";});
</script>
```

When this script in is my HTML file it is run by the browser automatically but when i put it in the JS file, it simply don't work without being called with a function name, and that's what i want to avoid due to unobtrusive javascript recommendations, so my question is "is there a way to make a script from JS file to be run automatically without a call from HTML event ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your script in the HTML with [defer](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-defer-attribute.html) attribute. This will run the code when HTML is ready. You could place the script tag at the end before `</body>` as well, but I prefer having it on top.

```
<head>
   <script src="/myscript.js" defer>
</head>
```

in myscript.js

```
(function() {
   // your code goes here
})();
```

Wrapping this into a function gives your own scope and another wrap into parenthesis and `()` at the end will do the execution.

Comment: So it's ok that's it's better to migrate all scripts from HTML file ? or is it just useless ? i mean do it have benefits for SEO etc.

Comment: This is very opinion based. I personally like have code separated from HTML, especially when you have much code. If you have just a very few lines, nothing speaks against inline code.